The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'. Dart & Flutter
void printSum({int x = 5, int y = 6, int? k}) {
  int sum = (k != null) ? (x + y) : (x + y + k);
  print(sum);
}

Error: Getting error on :(x + y + k) for variable k
"message": "The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'. ",

Your ternary expression are opposite. You have made it so if k are not null, you use (x + y) but if k are null, you then use (x + y + k).

this is due to the fact that k is nullable (int?), and the ternary expression is trying to use k in an arithmeticc operation where a non-nullable integer is expected.
you should provide a default value for k when it is null or handle the null case properly. One way to do this is by using the null-coalescing operator (??) to provide a default value for k.
  void printSum({int x = 5, int y = 6, int? k}) {
      int sum = (k == null) ? (x + y) : (x + y + k);
      print(sum);
    }


Heh.  Your text mentions using ??, but you don't use that in your example.  Perhaps you meant to include something like (k ?? 0)

yes  Sir @RandalSchwartz
I did this because we are dealing with math
and I didn't want to induce him to use default values
so I thought it would be better not to set a default value and leave it up to him

In this case though, the bounds of the problem are known.  I agree, in the general case, teaching "?? 0" would be bad.
